# stanford parser using jpype

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

when i try to use stanford parser using jpype i get the following error

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\stanford_parser\parser.py", line 103, 
   in **init**

```
self.parser = self.package_lexparser.LexicalizedParser(self.pcfg_model_fname)
```

File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\jpype_jpackage.py", line 55, 
  in **call**

```
raise TypeError, "Package "+self.__name+" is not Callable"
```

TypeError: Package edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser is not Callable

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same situation.
The reason was the incorrect path.

Is the path of jar file correct?

To start JVM, we call startJVM() like

```
jpype.startJVM(jpype.getDefaultJVMPath(), "-ea", "-Djava.class.path=%s" % (jar_path),)
```

If "jar_path" is incorrect, it does not work well.

Answer (score 2):

It's been long since this question has been asked but still if anyone comes wandering around, I once had the same issue and fixed it by fixing the path to the "stanford-parser.jar".
In my case (Ubuntu), I fixed this line in the "parser.py":

```
os.environ.setdefault("STANFORD_PARSER_HOME", "../3rdParty/stanford-parser/stanford-parser-2010-08-20")
```

and the error stopped reporting. Just make sure you're giving the right path to "stanford-parser.jar" and the PCFG files.